# AutoLISP count polylines and sum the quantity of them SORTED by linetype

Tags: lisp, autocad, cad, autolisp

This code here lists every polyline and their linetype to the command line one by one.

Is there a way to sum up the same linetype polylines and get a final result like:

X linetype : 5 piece
Y linetype : 2 piece
Z linetype : 8 piece

```
(defun c:TEST (/ ss i obj)
  (setvar "cmdecho" 0)
  (if
    (setq ss (ssget  '((0 . "*POLYLINE,LINE"))))
    (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
    (setq obj (vlax-ename->vla-object (ssname ss (setq i (1- i)))))
    (prompt (strcat "\nLe type de ligne est\n" (vla-get-Linetype  obj)))
      )
    )
  (setvar "cmdecho" 1)
  (princ)

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a little function for yourself,

```
(defun incr (key tbl)
  (cond
    ((null tbl) 
       ;; no key in tbl - create new entry
       ;; with the count of 1
      (list (cons key 1)))
    ((= key (caar tbl)) 
       ;; key is in the car of tbl -- increment the count
      (cons (cons key (+ 1 (cdar tbl)))
            (cdr tbl)))
    (T ;; key is in the cdr of tbl -- keep on searching
       ;; while preserving this entry, in the car
      (cons (car tbl)
        (incr key (cdr tbl))))))
```

Now we can use it,

```
(defun c:TEST (/ ss i obj key tbl)
  
  (if (setq ss (ssget  '((0 . "*POLYLINE,LINE"))))
    (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
      (setq obj (vlax-ename->vla-object (ssname ss (setq i (1- i)))))
      ;;  here:
      (setq key (vla-get-Linetype obj))
      (setq tbl (incr key tbl))))
      
  tbl)
```

In developing the `incr` function we followed the principle of "correctness first, efficiency later" i.e. we first write the simplest code which does the job. In particular, if each of your `N` polylines will have a different linetype, the use of this version of `incr` will contribute the time quadratic in `N` to the total execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of an association list, constructed in the same manner as the counter used as part of my [Block Counter](http://lee-mac.com/simpleblockcounter.html) tutorial.

You can implement this in the following way:

```
(defun c:test ( / a i l s x )
    (if (setq s (ssget '((0 . "LINE,POLYLINE"))))
        (repeat (setq i (sslength s))
            (if (setq i (1- i)
                      x (cond ((cdr (assoc 6 (entget (ssname s i))))) ("BYLAYER"))
                      a (assoc x l)
                )
                (setq l (subst (cons x (1+ (cdr a))) a l))
                (setq l (cons  (cons x 1) l))
            )
        )
    )
    l
)
```

A couple of additional points to note:

- You don't necessarily need to turn to ActiveX - the object linetype is held by DXF group 6 in the DXF data, else the linetype is set to `ByLayer` if this group is absent.
- There is no need to alter the setting of the `CMDECHO` system variable, as we're not calling any standard AutoCAD commands whose output would need to be suppressed.

Comment: subst returns *"A list, with newitem replacing all occurrences of olditem"* so not only will it be linear just the same is my `incr`, it won't even stop on the first found match and will always search through the list to its end, even though the keys in it are all unique by construction. so `incr` has the same cost as the `assoc` in your code, but you then call `subst` which my code entirely avoids. :)

Comment: Not trying to compete for efficiency, just offering an alternative potentially cleaner approach, since the use of `assoc`/`subst` is commonplace when working with association lists. Nevertheless, I appreciate your input and analysis of my code.